# iframes with google chrome internal page? (such as "chrome://history",bookmarks,etc)

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, history, bookmarks

I would be able to create a custom Home Page within two iframes, the first sourced from `chrome://bookmarks` and the second one from `chrome://history`.

I tried this:

```
<iframe src="chrome://history"></iframe>
```

but what I get is a blank page. Any ideas? Even if I try a simple

```
<a href="chrome://history">click</a>` , `<?php header("Location: chrome://history");?>
```

or some other usual ways to navigate, I get a blank page.

Comment: This sounds like a security issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access this info from a standalone page, but you can create a Chrome extension using corresponding APIs for [history](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html) and [bookmarks](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/bookmarks.html).